# AJAX post to django view in new window

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm trying to pass some form variables from a CreateView to a TemplateView that acts like a preview and renders the variables stored in `request.session`. I would like the preview to open in a new window. Without the ajax post, the preview loads well. However, when I added in the ajax post, the window opens without post data being passed.

The window is opened without post data. In views, form_valid() is bypassed. What am I doing wrong?

Is there a better way around this? Should I be capturing the submit event in jquery instead of a button click?

CreateView:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if form.is_valid():
        if self.request.POST.get('submit'):
            self.object = form.save(commit=False)
            self.object.profile = self.request.user.get_profile()
            self.object.save()
            return super(InvoiceCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
        elif self.request.POST.get('preview') and self.request.is_ajax():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            # Obtain form data, redirect only if template is not empty
            if data['template'] and data['customer']:
                self.request.session['template'] = data['template']
                self.request.session['customer'] = data['customer']
                return redirect('invoices:invoice_preview')
            else:
                messages.error(request, u"Unable to preview")
                return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
    else:
        messages.error(self.request, u"Invoice creation failed")
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

js:

```
$("#submit-id-preview").click(function() {    
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: false, // opens in tab if available
      url: "{% url "invoices:invoice_create" %}",
      data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{csrf_token}}",
      },
      success: function() {
          window.open("{% url "invoices:invoice_preview" %}", "_blank");
      },
      error: function() {
          alert('ouch'); // failed
      },
   });
   return false;
});
```

Edit (Preview View):

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(InvoicePreview, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    try:
        context['preview'] = True
        context['template'] = self.request.session['template']
        context['customer'] = self.request.session['event']
        context['preview_message'] = self.request.session['preview_message']
    except KeyError:
        return Http404 # just throw 404 if cookie fails
    return context
```

Preview takes the variables passed in the session to render some stuff, noticeably, in `template`, the css+html file references are stored and returned based on user's choice. So without the ajax post, the preview actually renders properly. Whereas when using ajax, I get a `argument of type 'type' is not iterable`.

Comment: What's the view you are accessing via `invoices:invoice_preview` exactly doing? Does it work if you access its url directly? Looks also like you don't need the `if form.is_valid()...` as in the generic `CreateView` the method `form_valid` only gets called if the form is valid...

Comment: Look what's in the server response: `error: function(err) { console.log(err); }`. Also have you added the `{{ csrf_token }}` template tag to your template?

Comment: @BernhardVallant I have added the preview view which is just a template view. dan-klasson: there's no server response, initially I had 403 but I sorted out the csrf issue with some js.